# WordPress Plugin Customize menu and submenu

Tags: wordpress

I made pretty good menu and sub menu in word press but when i click on menu (jobify) it says URL not found . My sub menus are working fine .

```
 <?php
```

//adding  custom admin menu 
add_action("admin_menu", "addMenu");

// function of custom admin menu
function addMenu() {
    add_menu_page("Jobify Menu", "Jobify", "manage_options", "jobifyAdminMenu",'', null, 3);
    add_submenu_page('jobify.php', 'user', 'User', 'manage_options', 'userSubMenu','user_manage');
    add_submenu_page('jobify.php', 'jobs', 'Jobs', 'manage_options', 'jobsSubMenu','jobs_mangae');
    add_submenu_page('jobify.php', 'setting', 'Setting', 'manage_options', 'settingSubMenu','setting_manage');
}

function user_manage() {

```
include plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'user.php';
```

}
?>

Comment: its totally unclear question can you eliminate its detaily or what code did you use for it

Comment: sorry before i forget to post my code @Selvakumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget the menu slug hence you getting error .

```
add_menu_page("Jobify Menu", "Jobify", "manage_options",$menu_slug, "jobifyAdminMenu", null, 3);
```

For example :

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_my_custom_menu_page' );

function register_my_custom_menu_page() {

    add_menu_page( 'custom menu title', 'custom menu', 'manage_options', 'myplugin/myplugin-admin.php', '', plugins_url( 'myplugin/images/icon.png' ), 6 );

}
```